# Preventing chrome/windows from downloading _Thumbs.db

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome

I created a local web app that just displays images and PDFs on a loop kiosk style. It has a basic Node.js http back end that feeds file paths to client browsers and the browsers use embed elements to display those files.

The issue is that when the client has run through the files provided and is told to reload chrome (It looks to be chrome that's doing it at any rate...) downloads a _Thumbs.db file. This app is meant to be a full screen kiosk and I would rather not have the downloads bar or any downloads prompt be present while it's running the slideshow.

I have disabled all the options for thumbnails on the windows side, but oddly enough it is a chrome download prompt that is the issue.

Can I prevent these files from being downloaded? If-Not any Idea how I can prevent Chrome from throwing a download prompt up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no problem with Chrome itself. It is rather your node.js backend app that feeds the URLs that finds Thumbs.db (despite it being hidden in Windows) and serves as a regular file to be displayed.

Comment: Where do you get the list of files to display from? Do you iterate the directory?

Comment: Yeah I use a directoryReader object, do you think it is picking up a hidden file? I checked for hidden files in the directory and found none. But that would make the most sense.

Comment: AFAIK Windows has at least two *levels* of hidden, that is normal hidden and system hidden files. ;) If there is such file in the directory it will probably be found by directoryReader, as I believe it ignores Windows Explorer visibility settings.

Comment: Well, I guess I will just omit the last result from the DirReader. See if that resolves it.

Comment: Yeah that was it, I revealed the system hidden files in the media directory and there was the thumbs file. You should answer this post and i will mark it.

Comment: For the sake of testing it is OK, but I hope you know that you cannot assume, that Thumbs.db is always going to be the last result. It's probably best to filter found files at least by extension (indicating file type that the browser should understand).

Comment: As you say, I set up a function to verify file extensions and remove unwanted file types.